# Format as Table in Excel

Tags: excel

I have a set of cells. All have a grey background color. When I mark all those cells and click on "Format as Table", the background colors of the cells don't change! I expect to see the first row in dark blue, second in light blue, third in dark blue again, and so on. If I mark all cells first and click on "clear formats", all cells are white. After this step it works: I can use "Format as Table" and get the expected output. However I cannot use "clear formats" first, because some cells have a red font. Because their content is important. I need to keep the red font in those cells! Why does "Format as Table" not change the background color of my cells according to the table scheme?

Comment: Try adding screenshot in your question.

Comment: Sorry but I can't, it's confidential data. But the description doesn't leave out any relevant information.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Format table indeed, applies a format to a range, but we even when you have a range of data formated as a table, you still can customize the background color of any cell.

To solve your problem, you should remove the background color of all cells before formatting as table. You can do it before or after formating your set of cells as table:

In example, I want to remove only the yellow background color of my cells, but keep the red font color.

[image]

If you use the option *clear formats* **it will delete ALL formats**. I want just to delete the background color, so use this instead:

1. Select all your set of cells
2. In the ribbon options, select the background color palette
3. Select the option "no fill color" (My excel is in spanish, I don't know the exact name of the option in english, but it should be there)

[image]

This will remove only the background color. Notice in the image that the font color is still red :)

Hope this works for you.

Comment: this works fine, however: if there are lines (like top border from previous table formatting), they will remain.

Comment: Glad it worked. To remove the lines, do the same but with the borders palette. Just select your set of cells and remove the borders. Another option would be to remove all formats and then color the red numbers again. Have you tried using Conditional formatting to automatize the red font color process?

Comment: I have done exactly what you've mentioned as "another option". Because I realized that there are not thaaat many cells with a red font :)